# print in new terminal window

Tags: python, linux, macos, terminal

i wrote an script that have multiple threads and in this threads i used "print()" code to print log activity about that thread, but the problem is i don't want to print all these logs at one terminal window. I found this code on ubuntu forum but it's not seems to be an standard way that simply could run on any OS including mac, ubuntu, fedora, ...
Is there any standard way to put out data in multiple terminal window or any better ida than this code?

```
import subprocess

pid = subprocess.Popen(args=["gnome-terminal", "--command=python test.py"]).pid
print pid
```

Comment: If there was a standard way to run a terminal program, your terminal program would probably be called `terminal` and not `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a shell (i.e. Bash) isn't really aware of multiple windows. You could use `screen` to manage multiple shell sessions.

For example to create a new screen session and execute `ifconfig` inside:

```
#create a unique name for the screen session (timestamp + random muber)
timestamp_random=my_$(date +%s)_$RANDOM
#create new screen session in detached mode
screen -S "$timestamp_random" -d -m
#stuff (write) command into that screen session + execute (by hitting newline/ENTER)
screen -r "$timestamp_random" -X stuff $'ifconfig\n'
```

You can then list all screen sessions with:

```
screen -list
```

And connect to each session to see the output:

```
screen -R [sessionname]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you mean from your question, but the following may help. Start a Terminal on OSX and press Command-N to get a second one - so you have 2 terminals open. Now click in either one and type:

```
tty
```

and it will tell you the name of the terminal associated with that window, e.g. `/dev/ttys000`.

Then go in the other open Terminal window and type:

```
echo Hello > /dev/ttys000        # or whatever the other Terminal was called
```

You should see the output of the `echo` command appear in the other Terminal's window and I think that is what you mean from your question.

Comment: is there a way to this from code? my app is single thread but I want it to show some stuff in one terminal and some other in another

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna You could use `std::cout` to write to your main window and `std::cerr` for output destined to the other window. Then, before you run your program, go in the other window to get its name, and, back in the main window, run `./yourProgram 2> /dev/ttyXXXX`. If you decide you want all the output in a single window later, just omit the `2> ...` part.